# Clicking a button that exists multiple times and is also nested

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have a problem that I would like to click a button that exists multiple times on the site and is nested into `cards`.

I am searching for the `card` where the name of the pet is `Bala`, see the attachment below, and I would like to click the `Detail` labeled button on it.

The furthest I have came with my solution is that I can search for the correct `card` and just simply click the first of these `Detail` buttons.

***HTML:***

```
<div _ngcontent-eng-1="" class="col-md-3 pt-3 pb-3">
            <app-pet _ngcontent-eng-1="" _nghost-eng-2="" class="dog"><div _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="pet">
  <!--template bindings={}--><div _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="card">
    <div _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="card-block">
      <h4 _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="card-title">Bala</h4> //Checking this?
      <h6 _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="card-subtitle mb-2">
        <!--template bindings={}--><div _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="badge badge-pill badge-success">
          New
        </div>
        <!--template bindings={}--><div _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="badge badge-pill badge-info">
          Important
        </div>
        &nbsp;
      </h6>
      <ul _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="list-group-item">
          <div _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="age">
            <span _ngcontent-eng-2="">Age: </span>
            <span _ngcontent-eng-2="">20</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="list-group-item">
          <div _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="type">
            <a _ngcontent-eng-2="" href="/pet/494">
              <img _ngcontent-eng-2="" src="/assets/dog.gif">
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="list-group-item">
          <a _ngcontent-eng-2="" class="btn btn-primary" href="/pet/494">
            Detail
          </a> //CLICK
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</app-pet>
</div>
```

***My code***

```
Then('I click on the Detail button', () => {
  cy.get('div.card').contains('Bala').find('a.btn.btn-primary').click();
});
```

This is what I have currently but I have already treid some different approaches, like `find('a').contains('Detail')` or `find('a').contains('btn.btn-primary')` and some other similar code snippets.

***Graphically***

[This is what the site looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar9wU.png)

Also I have browsed through some similar *SO* topics but those didn't quite work for me.

Comment: Do you have a site we can use a reference? It would make things easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea to find the card first. This is how you could change your test to do it.

```js
Then('I click on the Detail button', () => {
  cy.contains('div.card', 'Bala').find('a.btn.btn-primary').click();
})
```

You are specifying the element and the text in one command.

Comment: Seems like I was really close but yet so far :D
Thank you very much, it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eq` if you want to click a particular button:

```js
cy.contains('a', 'Detail').eq(0).click() //Clicks first Detail button
cy.contains('a', 'Detail').eq(1).click() //Clicks second Detail button
```

Or if you want to click all the buttons one by one you can use `each`:

```js
cy.contains('a', 'Detail').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).click()
})
```

Comment: I would like to click the button where the name of the pet is 'Bala'. However I didn't really find a way to do that.

Comment: How about you try this `cy.contains('Bala').find('.btn.btn-primary').click()` ?

Comment: Doesn't work unforunately :/

I have also tried:

```cy.contains('Bala').find('btn.btn-primary').click()```,


```cy.contains('Bala').find('btn-primary').click()```,


```cy.contains('Bala').find('a.btn.btn-primary').click()```,


```cy.contains('Bala').contains('Detail').click()```,


but they all end up throwing an error because Cypress searches it in ```h4.card-title```.